# code ole automation excel error

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

This code gives me error

```
ex.Cells [3, 2]. HorizontalAlignment: = xlright;

ex.Cells [row, 1]. NumberFormat: = 'dd / mm / yy, @';
```

how can I fix this?

thanks

Comment: Please stop putting tag information in your subject line. Tags are available for a reason. Please use them. (You also keep putting `XE3` it the title, but using an `XE2` tag. Make up your mind - is it XE2 or XE3?) You also need to be more specific. "this code gives me error" has no meaning if you don't tell us what the error is - we can't see your screen from where we are. What is the **specific error** you're getting? Which line of code causes the error? The first one refers to `Sheet.Cells` and the second to `ex.Cells`; what are `Sheet` and `ex`?

Comment: You did not say what the error was. But you can see the error. So why is it not in the question? It's not much fun trying to guess. Please always include full error messages, copied verbatim. -1 until the question is fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do not use VCL TExcelApplication and other components (I found this component installed and do not know where to find and how to install it. If you can give me some advice thank you. .... I just started with delphi) I used the code you posted, but running, I get this error: "unable to set the property for the class Numberformat range" - to date - and "Unable to set the HorizontalAlignment property for the class range" - for xlright. Sorry, but I am a beginner ... thanks

Comment: Thank you.
The problem is in this line of code:

XLApp.Workbooks [1]. Worksheets. [1] Range ['C1: C5']. NumberFormat: = 'dd / mm / yy';

the error is:

Numberformat impossible to set the range for the class.

I do not know how to fix ....

Answer (score 1):

Based on your other questions, you're using late binding (using a `Variant`) instead of early binding (using the VCL `TExcelApplication` and other components). This means that the specific types like `xlRight` are not defined, because you haven't used the type library import that provides them. You'll have to define them yourself:

```delphi
var
  ...
  NewAlign: OleVariant;
const
  xlBottom = $FFFFEFF5;
  xlLeft = $FFFFEFDD;
  xlRight = $FFFFEFC8;
  xlTop = $FFFFEFC0;
  xlHAlignCenter = $FFFFEFF4;
  xlHAlignCenterAcrossSelection = $00000007;
  xlHAlignDistributed = $FFFFEFEB;
  xlHAlignFill = $00000005;
  xlHAlignGeneral = $00000001;
  xlHAlignJustify = $FFFFEFDE;
  xlHAlignLeft = $FFFFEFDD;
  xlHAlignRight = $FFFFEFC8;
begin
  // XLApp is the instance of Excel you set up from your previous
  // questions
  XLApp.Workbooks[1].Worksheets[1].Range['C1:C5'].NumberFormat := 'dd/mm/yy';
  NewAlign := xlHAlignRight;
  XLApp.Workbooks[1].Worksheets[1].Range['C1:C5'].HorizontalAlignment := NewAlign;
end;
```

Assigning `dd/mm/yy @` makes no sense, because it's either a date format `dd/mm/yy` or text `@`, but not both.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I do not use VCL TExcelApplication and other components (I found this component installed and do not know where to find and how to install it. If you can give me some advice thank you. .... I just started with delphi)
I used the code you posted, but running, I get this error:
"unable to set the property for the class Numberformat range" - to date -
and
"Unable to set the HorizontalAlignment property for the class range" - for xlright.

Sorry, but I am a beginner ...

thanks

Comment: Go to [Deborah Pate's Site](http://www.djpate.freeserve.co.uk/AutoExcl.htm#FormatRange). It's old (from around Delphi 5s days, IIRC), but it still has some useful information about working with Excel automation with both early and late binding.

Comment: As far as how to find and use `TExcelApplication`, that's a *separate question from this*. If you want to ask about it, post a new question. :-) @David: Thanks for the edit.